# Pass parameters to schedule

Tags: python, schedule

How can I pass parameters to [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)?

The function I want to get called:

```
def job(param1, param2):
    print(str(param1) + str(param2))
```

How I schedule it:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
```

How can I pass a parameter to `do(job)`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In general with this kind of thing you can always do this:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(lambda: job('Hello ', 'world!'))
```

Looking at the source:

```
def do(self, job_func, *args, **kwargs):
    """Specifies the job_func that should be called every time the
    job runs.
    Any additional arguments are passed on to job_func when
    the job runs.
    :param job_func: The function to be scheduled
    :return: The invoked job instance
    """
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
```

We see that you can also do this:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job, 'Hello ', 'world!')
```

Or, as the code suggests, an alternative to the generic `lambda` method is:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(functools.partial(job, 'Hello ', 'world!'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to use lamda function, can you tell me how to use it and when to use it ? I used do(job(param1, param2)) but It was error. What the different between do(job(param1, param2)) and do(lambda: job('Hello ', 'world!')) ? Thanks

Comment: `lambda: ...` returns a function with no arguments, similar to  `def function_name(): return ...` but it lets you make the code a bit shorter. `do(job(param1, param2))` simply calls `job(param1, param2)` immediately and passes the result to `do` which makes no sense.

Comment: is it like return a void function in Java or C# ? so it does not return anything ?

Comment: No, it returns the expression after the `:`. Google "python lambda" and do some reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job, 'do something', 'like this')
```

My friend tried the above syntax but it didn't work, so if it does not work you can use

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job('do something', 'like this'))
```

His schedule statement was not like this exactly it was like this -

```
schedule.every().monday.at('8:30')do(job('It was', 'like this'))
```

Comment: Not working for me.