# Is it possible to send message to a specific channel using discord.py in another file?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i have some file named someFuncs.py and bot.py, where I can send messages to channel. However bot.py imported someFunc.py, and I can't import bot.py in someFunct.py(where I want to send message to a specific channel). Is there any possible solutions to send message from someFunc.py?

someFunc.py

```
def func():

    #want send some messages from this file to a specific channel,
```

bot.py

```
import someFunc.py

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone="Asia/Seoul")
scheduler.add_job(someFunc.func, 'cron', hour='19, 19', minute='47, 48')

try:
    scheduler.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    scheduler.shutdown()
load_dotenv()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

btw someFunc.py is scheduled and runs at specific time and I can't/don't know how to pass values to bot.py, so solution as "just pass someFunc.py variables to bot.py" is seems impossible to me.

Comment: If you have a circular import problem, you can import a module only in the function where you need it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I used import modules at both files, and it's still circular import problems, do you have any ideas to try?

Comment: Import in a function like: `def f1(): from x import f2; f2()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do about "ImportError: Cannot import name X" or "AttributeError: ... (most likely due to a circular import)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/what-can-i-do-about-importerror-cannot-import-name-x-or-attributeerror) See the third answer about importing the entire module instead of `from x import y`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781062/pass-parameters-to-schedule is also related